# glfwCreateWindow returns NULL on Mac OS

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, glfw, glew

I'm doing my OpenGL homework on Xcode10.0 Mac OS 10.14 using glew2.1 and glfw3.2, but glfwCreateWindow always returns NULL. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    GLFWwindow* win;

    if(!glfwInit()){
        return -1;
    }

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    win = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "test", NULL, NULL);

    if(!win)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if(!glewInit())
    {
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(win);
    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(win)){
        glfwSwapBuffers(win);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
    glfwTerminate();
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    return 0;
}
```

if I delete 4 glfwWindowHint sentences, a window will show up but it's dark,and Xcode console will throw an error:Setting  as the first responder for window , but it is in a different window ((null))! This would eventually crash when the view is freed. The first responder will be set to nil.

Comment: According to [http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/intro_guide.html#error_handling](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/intro_guide.html) glfwCreateWindow returns NULL when an error has occurred. Try reading the error using glfwSetErrorCallback as shown on [http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/intro_guide.html#error_handling](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/intro_guide.html#error_handling).

Comment: Also you are making the windows context current after glewInit(), you should be setting context current before glewInit.

Comment: you can make a callback error function to check the detail reason. \n void error_callback(int, const char* err_str){
    std::cout<<"GLFW Error:"<<err_str<<std::endl;
}.   and call this callback function in main :  glfwSetErrorCallback(error_callback);

Comment: same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70515157/trouble-creating-a-glfw-opengl-window-in-c

Answer (score 4):

These two lines:

```
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
```

were causing the issue for me. Once I removed them, glfwCreateWindow() was no longer returning null.