# Trouble Creating a GLFW OpenGL Window in C++

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

Here is the current bit of code I'm working on:

```
int main() {

    glfwInit();

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 0);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);

    GLFWwindow *window = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "OpenGL", NULL, NULL);

    if (nullptr == window) {
        std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW Window" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();

        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
```

At runtime, the window is not created, and I get the failure message.  I am not understanding why window is a nullptr, when I defined it. Am I missing something?

Comment: What is the OS? Are you sure that `GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR` should be 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the GLFW documentation, the value for the `GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE` window hint *must* be `GLFW_OPENGL_ANY_PROFILE` if the requested OpenGL context version is less than 3.2 (and GLFW has [a platform-independent check built-in](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/blob/fd79b02840a36b74e4289cc53dc332de6403b8fd/src/context.c#L111-L120) whenever [`glfwCreateWindow` is called](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/blob/fd79b02840a36b74e4289cc53dc332de6403b8fd/src/window.c#L186)).

See: https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/window_guide.html#GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE_hint

> **GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE** specifies which OpenGL profile to create the context for. Possible values are one of GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE or GLFW_OPENGL_COMPAT_PROFILE, or GLFW_OPENGL_ANY_PROFILE to not request a specific profile. If requesting an OpenGL version below 3.2, GLFW_OPENGL_ANY_PROFILE must be used. If OpenGL ES is requested, this hint is ignored.

In particular the part: "If requesting an OpenGL version below 3.2, GLFW_OPENGL_ANY_PROFILE must be used."

You will get a GLFW error in your case. In particular, [exactly this one](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/blob/fd79b02840a36b74e4289cc53dc332de6403b8fd/src/context.c#L111-L120) - regardless of the platform/OS, which you would see if you had setup a GLFW error handler function via [glfwSetErrorCallback()](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.0/group__error.html#gaa5d796c3cf7c1a7f02f845486333fb5f).